# Python/SPSS: pattern in names not consecutive

Tags: python, spss

Starting to use SPSS/Python, I need to average variables whose names contain two different strings. I found many examples for individual strings (or numbers, etc.), but my strings are not adjacent.

var1_blabla_def_blabla_jkl

var2_blabla_blabla_def_jkl

var3_blabla_jkl_blabla_blabla

How do I get the mean over var1 and var2, containing "def" AND "jkl", and not var3 that contains only jkl? I am not sure what the regular expression would be for this pattern and how then to feed this into something like spss.Submit('compute %s=mean(%s))

Many thanks for any help and hints, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify this further in two ways.  First, the spssaux.VariableDict object has a built-in filter mechanism using a regular expression.  So you could write
vars = spssaux.VariableDict(pattern="(.*jkl)|(.*def)).variables
to get the list.

The second way would  be to use the SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES extension command, which is included in the Python Essentials to generate a macro according to selection criteria that include name patterns, variable type, and other properties.  This could then be used in regular syntax.  The command appears on the Utilities menu as Define Variable Macro.

Comment: Great, thank you, (pattern="(.*jkl)|(.*def)) works also. I didn't know the structure of this expression. Thanks a lot!

Comment: vars = spssaux.VariableDict(pattern="(.*correct)").variables

Comment: Sorry: vars = spssaux.VariableDict(pattern="(.*jkl)|(.*def))".variables

Answer (score 1):

Creating some fake data:

```
data list list/rowID var1_blabla_def_blabla_jkl var2_blabla_blabla_def_jkl  var3_blabla_jkl_blabla var4_jkl_blabla_def var5_blabla_def_blabla.
begin data
1 20 30 40 50 60
2 21 31 41 51 61
3 22 32 42 52 62
4 23 33 43 53 63
end data.
```

Now the following will calculate a new variable which is the mean of all other variables who's names contain both "jkl" and "def":

```
begin program.
import spss, spssaux
origVars=spssaux.GetVariableNamesList()
filtVars=filter(lambda v: 'def' in v and 'jkl' in v, origVars)
spss.Submit("compute MNvar=mean(%s)." %(", ".join(filtVars)))
end program.
```

Comment: Great, works beautifully. Thank you so much, this is a big help !